# How do I remove the Conduit toolbar that comes with µTorrent?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extensions, utorrent, adware

I have recently installed µTorrent in my computer and unfortunately the Conduit adware came bundled with it.

Basically, it installs a toolbar on all browsers and replaces the default search and initial homepage to that of Conduit. I have tried to run AdAware and MalwareBytes but both were unable to remove it.

Search results on Google tell me to remove the Conduit software in the *Control Panel → Remove Programs*, but it's not listed there. Other suggestions involved going into the extensions configuration in Chrome, but it's not listed there as well.

Anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `.CRX` file under `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\CRE`. Delete this file

Run `regedit` (start menu, type regedit, press Enter)

Click `Edit -> Find` and search for the directory mentioned above. Delete any entries that pointed to it

*Warning: backup your registry before deleting any of its entries.*

Answer (score 0):

It has been suggested to use this uninstaller to remove it.

http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_uninstall_features.html

Answer (score 0):

**AdwCleaner** is a program that searches for and deletes Adware, Toolbars, Potentially Unwanted Programs (PUP), and browser Hijackers from your computer. I have used it in the past and it is the only program that has trully been effective at removing such "nasties".

Instructions on how to use the program can be found here by scrolling down the page:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

Then simply click where it says **Download Now @BleepingComputer** at the start of the page

Answer (score 0):

I went the Remove way: note that it's listed under programs as `Search Protect` made by `Conduit`